# Pass Data Between Angular UI Modals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am looking to pass data between modals using Angular UI. Here is the modalController that defines the controller and view partial for each modal.

```
app.controller("modalController", function($scope, $modal){

$scope.registerOpen = function(size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "templates/registrationModal.html",
        controller: 'modalInstanceController',
        size: size
    });
};

$scope.categoriesOpen = function(size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "templates/categoriesModal.html",
        controller: 'modalInstanceController',
        size: size
    });
};

});
```

Here is the Modal Instance Controller which is called for each modal which handles closing and opening the modal

```
 app.controller("modalInstanceController", function($scope, $modalInstance){

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

});
```

Here is the register modal body that has two nested controllers. the model formData points to en empty object inside of registerFormController.

Register Modal Body:

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-controller="registerFormController">
        <div class="facebookButton">
            <div class="lucida">Sign In With Facebook</div>
        </div>

            <div class="registerForm" ng-controller="modalController">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="registerEmail block" ng-model="formData.email">

                <input type="password" placeholder="password" required class="registerPassword block" ng-model="formData.password">

                <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password2" required ui-validate=" '$value==formData.password' " ui-validate-watch=" 'formData.password' "class="registerPassword2 block" ng-model="formData.password2">

                <span ng-show="registerForm.password2.$error.validator" class="block">Passwords do not match!</span>

                <!-- ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid" -->
                <button type="button" class="create-account" ng-click="categoriesOpen('md')" >Next</button>
          </div>  
          {{formData}}
    </div>
```

Categories Modal:

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-controller="registerFormController">
            <div class="registerForm">
                <label class="event-category" ng-model="formData.sports" btn-checkbox>Sports</label>
                <label class="event-category" ng-model="formData.bars" btn-checkbox>Bars</label>
                <label class="event-category" ng-model="formData.family" btn-checkbox>Family</label>
                <label class="event-category" ng-model="formData.movies" btn-checkbox>Movies</label>


                <button type="submit" ng-click="processForm(); confirmationOpen()" class="create-account" ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
          </div>
          {{formData}}
    </div>
```

Here, in the categories modal, {{formData}} doesn't reflect the input values from the previous modal. I think I might need to resolve and return the data back to the controller to pass it along to the next, but not sure how to implement this.

Finally the registerFormController

```
app.controller('registerFormController', function($scope, $http){


$scope.formData = {};

$scope.processForm = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/user',
        data: $scope.formData,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    }).success(function(data){

        if(!data) {
            console.log('not working');
        } else if (data) {
            console.log('successfully POSTing!');
        }

    });
};

 });
```

Whew... Sorry for the long post. Somewhat new to angular so I really appreciate the responses and help. I can convert this to a codepen if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data between controllers with AngularJS service. I have made simple example:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker">
        <div ng-controller="registerFormController">
            <h3>Register Form Controller</h3>
            <input type="text" ng-model="formData.firstName">
            <br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="formData.lastName">
            <br>
            {{formData}}
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="modalInstanceController">
            <h3>Modal Instance Controller</h3>
            <input type="text" ng-model="formData.firstName">
            <br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="formData.lastName">
            <br>
            {{formData}}
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
            app.controller('registerFormController', function($scope, registerDataService){
                $scope.formData = registerDataService.data;
            }).controller("modalInstanceController", function($scope, registerDataService){
                $scope.formData = registerDataService.data;
            }).factory('registerDataService', function() {
                var registerDataService = {};
                registerDataService.data = {
                    'firstName': 'Kostya',
                    'lastName': 'Shkryob'
                };

                return registerDataService;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kostya, Thank you so much. This will be invaluable moving forward in my project. Thanks.